# ajax nonce wordpress security. Can I use this to protect my json data from scraping?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, security, nonce

I am building a wordpress plugin with ajax and am looking to protect the json data from prying eyes and data scrapers.

My thoughts... server side, I send a nonce in a hidden html field within a form submission to a jquery script.

This script requests via GET some json data from a php file.

Prior to the php file responding to the GET request it first checks that the nonce is valid and if so, returns the json data. If not, returns nothing / dies / does something cool to lock out that IP address for a certain amount of time.

If a scraper goes directly to the data file with a get request, but the incorrect nonce, no data is returned. If a person peeks into the data file, but they don't have the nonce, then they will see nothing... is this correct? I am aware that the nonce is use only once, so even if they have an old nonce, they still won't be able to view the data unless a new nonce is generated by wordpress?

Is this possible or have I completely missed the point of the nonce?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you have the general idea on how Wordpress nonce works, but here's some reading anyway:

[Mark Jaquith - WordPress Nonces](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/06/02/wordpress-203-nonces/)
[Vladimir Prelovac - Using Nonces in WordPress Plugins](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/improving-security-in-wordpress-plugins-using-nonces)

I think you need to keep in mind a few things:

1. If all this functionality is primarily utilized on the Admin side of Wordpress, then you have to also understand that in order for a scraper to even be considered a threat, it would require the same credentials as a normal user. How can a scraper scrape your Admin Panel without a Username and Password? It can't. If you're satisfied with the core security Wordpress employs on its own, then your additional Nonce functionality is a lot of flash and flare to eliminate a threat that doesn't exist.
2. If your sensitive data is to be kept apart from the Admin panel, then Nonce can be one way of securing it, I suppose, but that's really not the purpose of Nonce. There are many cleaner ways of securing your information rather than relying on Wordpress' Nonce functionality, so consider looking into a more relevant alternative.
3. IP Banning is neat and all, but you also have to understand that this is not a foolproof method, as IP addresses can be easily faked, and it might have some unintended consequences. You might be able to succeed in banning the IP address of somebody who attempted to access private information, but what if that person was attempting this over a Network? You've effectively banned an entire network from accessing your site, not just a single person.

All in all, you should just make sure that you're using the right tools for any particular job. I think using Nonce for this purpose is certainly possible, but it is far from ideal.